# Substantiv (Gen.) + nach

Tags: translation, meaning

Ich bin über den folgenden Satz in einem Text gestolpert, der mir echten Kopfschmerzen bereitet:

> Ziel war die Erschaffung eines Volkes der wiedererstarkten 'echten' und 'reinen' Türken, **der Herkunft und des Lebens nach.**

Ich verstehe schon, was mit dem ersten Satzteil gemeint wird. Um es ins Englische zu übersetzen, etwa: "The aim was the creation of a people composed of reinvigorated 'true' and 'pure' Turks, ..."

Was wird aber mit dem zweiten Teil gemeint? Ich stütze mich wieder auf die möglichen englischen Übersetzungen:

- "The aim was the creation of a people composed of reinvigorated 'true' and 'pure' Turks, *in accordance with heritage and life.*" [Das sagt mir als Muttersprachler nichts... Dann muss man sich fragen, gemäß *welcher* Herkunft und *welchem* Leben?]
- "The aim was the creation of a people composed of reinvigorated
  'true' and 'pure' Turks, *in terms of both heritage and life.*" [Je mehr ich diese Übersetzung lese, desto besser klingt es...]
- "The aim was the [re]creation of a people composed of reinvigorated 'true' and 'pure' Turks, *of heritage and of life.*" [Ich glaube nicht, dass man 'nach' im Zusammenhang mit einem Substantiv verwenden kann, um die Bedeutung des Substantives zu erweitern.]

Es bleibt hoffentlich auch noch die Möglichkeit, dass es einfach um einen blöd geschriebenen Satz geht. Um noch was Zusammenhang zu geben, hier der ganze Satz:

> "So ist die Skepsis gegen das Rassekonzept als Skepsis gegenüber der damaligen
>   Anwendungsmöglichkeit und nicht gegen das Konzept als solches zu verstehen. Mit der jungtürkischen Revolution und der Durchsetzung des jungtürkischen Programms sollte gerade die Anwendung des Rassegedankens möglich werden. Ziel war die Erschaffung eines Volkes der wiedererstarkten »echten« und »reinen« Türken, der Herkunft und des Lebens nach - eine Aufgabe, die Kemal Atatürk über vulgarisierende anthropologische und sprachwissenschaftliche Ansätze zu vollenden versuchte, um dabei an der kurdischen Frage zu scheitern."

Comment: Es scheint mir kein Dativ zu sein. Die Form _der Herkunft_ ist ja mehrdeutig, aber _des Lebens_ ist eindeutig Genitiv. Nicht daß das Sinn ergäbe …

Comment: Du hast vollkommen Recht. Es muss ja Genitiv sein - den Titel werde ich nun ändern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der zweite Teil qualifizert die Adjektive *echt* und *rein*. Also "echt nach der Herkunft" (true according to/in terms of heritage), "rein nach dem Lebensstil/der Art, wie ihr Leben geführt wird" usw. Das lässt offen, ob es "echt in Bezug auf die Herkunft" (Aspekt) oder "echt durch die Herkunft" (Grund) ist.

Ich weiß nicht, was die beste englische Übersetzung ist, aber diese Frage gehört auch nicht in dieses Forum. :-)

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Antwort! Ich verstehe aber immer noch nicht, warum die Substantive hier im Wesfall geschrieben sind, anstatt der gebräuchlichen Formulierung von 'Substantiv (DAT) + nach'. (Siehe z.B. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nach#German) Hast Du vielleicht eine Meinung dazu?

Comment: @Milchgesicht: Gute Frage. In altem Deutsch gab es *nach* auch mit dem Genitiv (siehe [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GN00071) unter III), aber das hier scheint ein moderner Text zu sein. Wenn man "Leben" durch einen klareren Ausdruck wie z.B. "Lebenstil" ersetzt, würde ich auf alle Fälle Dativ nehmen. *Wenn* es also kein Fehler ist, hängt es vielleicht damit zusammen. Den Autor kontaktieren und ihn fragen? :-)

Comment: @Milchgesicht: Vielleicht sind auch irgendwo unterwegs ein paar Worte verloren gegangen, und der Satz hieß ursprünglich "...,  der Herkunft und **der Art** des Lebens nach" oder so.

Comment: @dirkt, wie würde der ganze Satz mit Lebensstil (statt Leben) und Dativ lauten?

Comment: @dirkt Ich bin auch der Meinung, dass ein paar Worte verloren gegangen sind. "..., der Herkunft und der Art des Lebens nach" passt viel besser dazu. Nochmal vielen Dank!

Comment: @Milchgesicht: "..., der Herkunft und dem Lebensstil nach"